# How to save Java Object in shared preference

Tags: android, android-layout

I get `JSON` from a service, i save it in preference, and when user needs to check session or fetch data, he uses this method `getProfileObject()`, and it returns `ArrayList` in return.

This is my method that is responsible to get `Json` from `preference` and generate `ArrayList` by using `Gson`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=ApplicationContext.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences(USER_DATA_PREFERENCE, ApplicationContext.MODE_PRIVATE);

profileObject= sharedPreferences.getString(PROFILE_OBJECT, "");

if(!profileObject.isEmpty()) {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    this.dataList = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(profileObject, Profile.class));
    return dataList;
}
```

Now i want to avoid this `Gson` step each time, I want to store `arrayList` is `shared preference`, Is it possible to store `java array list` in shared preference.

Comment: have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Comment: First of all I have doubt on your data structure. Why it is List? And no, you can not do it without GSON. You can consider using database instead it, but again why List?

Comment: @PankajKumar : its because Gson `Arrays.asList` returns `List`

Answer (score 0):

Try using View Model class which will save it globally through out  the activity life cycle.

hope this helps : 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..
Store Array list as serializable object like below ..

```
editor.putString("key", ObjectSerializer.serialize(currentTasks));// define arrayList
```

retrive the value.

```
 currentTasks=(ArrayList<task>)ObjectSerializer.deserialize(prefs.getString(TASKS, ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<task>())));



   Gson dataJson = new Gson();
   String userObject = dataJson.toJson(response.body());
```

after that it store sharedpreference userObject and get data.

Comment: *`Now i want to avoid this Gson step each time,`* did you read the question?

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void setArrayListPreference(Context context, ArrayList<String> list, String key){
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(list);
        editor.putString(key, json);
        editor.apply();
    }

public static ArrayList<String> getArrayListPreference(Context context, String key){
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = prefs.getString(key, null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
```